# Bluebird Promises: Dynamically build props object, yet execute in parallel

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

For the given example here:

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#props---promise

```
Promise.props({
    pictures: getPictures(),
    comments: getComments(),
    tweets: getTweets()
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.tweets, result.pictures, result.comments);
});
```

Now, if I want to build the props object dynamically? Like

```
var propObj = {};

if (cond1) {
    propObj.tweets = getTweets();
}
if (cond2) {
    propObj.pictures = getPictures();
}
if (cond3) {
    propObj.comments = getComments();
}

Promise.props(propObj)
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Above code wouldn't work as expected. The functions getTweets, getPictures, getComments would execute imperatively during the construction of propsObj.

However, What I am actually looking for is to execute those functions in parallel during the `Promises.props(propObj)` phase and then return the result object. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with them executing before `Promises.props(propObj)`? They all return promises and will be queued and technically run parallel. When assigning in the `Promises.props(propObj)` line they get executed sequentially (to return the promise) while the object is being built. `Promises.props(propObj)` just waits for all properties in the `propObj` to complete before calling `.then()`.

Comment: Your example is working identically to the Bluebird code example.  In the Bluebird example, the functions `getPictures()` and `getComments()` and `getTweets()` are called BEFORE `Promise.props()` is actually called - the same as in your code example.  What is passed to `Promise.props()` is an object who's proeprties are promises.  The initial function has already been called that generated the promises and the operation is already in flight.  Your code is NOT working differently than the Bluebird example.  Not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You do, of course, realize that if your functions are actually just synchronous function calls that there is no such thing as parallel operation of synchronous function calls in regular Javascript because the main thread here is single threaded. Only one thing actually executes at a time. If the operations are asynchronous (e.g. networking or async file I/O), then you get some actual parallel action after the call is initiated because native code libraries are handling things in other threads after the initial call has returned), but that does not happen for regular synchronous function calls.

Comment: You could avoid the `propObj` assignment by writing `Promise.props({/* object literal */}).then(...);`.

Comment: @Steven10172 thanks. That clarified my understanding

Comment: @jfriend00. That makes total sense. I was thinking it incorrectly. Also I had network I/O in my mind and thus the whole 'running in parallel' doubt

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comments into an answer to perhaps wrap up this question...

Your example is working identically to the Bluebird code example. In the Bluebird example, the functions `getPictures()` and `getComments()` and `getTweets()` are called BEFORE Promise.props() is actually called - the same as in your code example. What is passed to `Promise.props()` is an object whose properties are promises.

So, what happens here in both your example and the Bluebird example is the following:

1. `if (cond1)`, initiate `getTweets()` and assign the resulting promise to propObj.tweets.  That async operation continues in the background.
2. `if (cond2)`, initiate `getPictures()` and assign the resulting promise to propObj.pictures.  That async operation continues in the background.
3. `if (cond3)`, initiate `getComments()` and assign the resulting promise to propObj.comments.  That async operation continues in the background.
4. Call `promise.props(propObj)` which just iterates the properties of `propObj` and then waits to call the `.then()` handler until all promises it finds are done.
5. Eventually all the async operations finish and the `.then()` handler is called.

The initial function has already been called that generated the promises and the operation is already in flight. Your code is NOT working differently than the Bluebird example. Not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

You do, of course, realize that if your functions are actually just synchronous function calls that there is no such thing as parallel operation of synchronous function calls in regular Javascript because the main thread here is single threaded. Only one thing actually executes at a time. If the operations are asynchronous (e.g. networking or async file I/O), then you get some actual parallel action after the call is initiated because native code libraries are handling things in other threads after the initial call has returned), but that does not happen for regular synchronous function calls.

Comment: The problem with this is that they'll never execute and return a promise

Comment: @Steven10172 - answer rewritten.